# Set modifier height width to coil Image or AsyncImage and scal the image loaded from url

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil, composable

I'm using coil library to load images in my composable view and I want to define fix height and width for my coil Image composable, however the modifier is missing in the coil Image composable class, following is the code snippet I'm using.

```
AsyncImage(
        model = limit.imgUrl,
        contentDescription = null
    )
```

How I can make the width and height fixed irrespective of the image resolution.

Comment: Every `AsyncImage` function in coil library has `Modifier` param.  https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/blob/main/coil-compose-base/src/main/java/coil/compose/AsyncImage.kt

Comment: ContentScale.FillWidth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply `modifier = Modifier.height(xx.dp).width(xx.dp)` to the [`AsyncImage`](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-compose-base/coil.compose/-async-image.html):

```
   AsyncImage(
        //...
        modifier = Modifier.height(300.dp).width(100.dp)
    )
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the Modifier to set the width and height, but be sure to set `contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds`, or it won't resize the image properly:

```
AsyncImage(
   model = limit.imgUrl,
   contentDescription = null,
   contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
   modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp).width(80.dp)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me ! Image may get stretched hence I prefer ContentScale.Crop